# Why is this javascript calculator not working?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I've tried to make this simple calculator in javascript. I've checked the names of the classes and all, but I can't find any problem. Besides the console does not show any problem either, but still nothing happens when I click on the buttons.
This is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<section class="calculator">
  <form>
    <div class="previous_op"></div>
    <div class="current_op"></div>
</form>
<button  class ='clearBtn span-two'>AC</button>
<button class ='delBtn'>DEL</button>
<button class='btn btn-orange' data-num='/'>/</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='1'>1</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='2'>2</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='3'>3</button>
<button class='btn btn-orange' data-num='*'>*</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='4'>4</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='5'>5</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='6'>6</button>
<button class='btn btn-orange' data-num='+'>+</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='7'>7</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='8'>8</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='9'>9</button>
<button class='btn btn-orange' data-num='-'>-</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='.'>.</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='0'>0</button>
<button class ='span-two equalBtn'>=</button>
</section>
  </body>
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</html>
```

And this is the javascript file:

```
const btns = document.querySelector('.btn');
const prevOp = document.querySelector('.previous_op');
const currOp = document.querySelector('.current_op');
const equalBtn = document.querySelector('.equalBtn');
const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.clearBtn');
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector('.delBtn');


for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    let number= btns[i].getAttribute('data-num');
    currOp.value += number;
  })
}

equalBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let value = eval(currOp.value);
  currOp.value = value;
})
clearBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  currOp.value = '';
})
```

Comment: `const btns = document.querySelector('.btn');` you probably want `.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: `.querySelector` selects a single element only, and the loop is never run.

Comment: i changed the .querySelector( ) to .querySelectorAll( ) but now the console says it cant read property 'getAttribute' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U have three missing

1) make querySelector to querySelectorAll for Nodelist

2) write this inspide of btns[i]

3) initialize your currOp.value

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
const prevOp = document.querySelector('.previous_op');
const currOp = document.querySelector('.current_op');
const equalBtn = document.querySelector('.equalBtn');
const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.clearBtn');
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector('.delBtn');
 currOp.value="";

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
   
    let number= this.getAttribute('data-num');
    currOp.value += number;
    currOp.innerHTML=currOp.value;
     console.log( currOp.value)
  })
}

equalBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let value = eval(currOp.value);
  currOp.value = value;
  currOp.innerHTML=currOp.value;
  
})
clearBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  currOp.value = '';
  currOp.innerHTML='';
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport">
    <title>Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<section class="calculator">
  <form>
    <div class="previous_op"></div>
    <div class="current_op"></div>
</form>
<button  class ='clearBtn span-two'>AC</button>
<button class ='delBtn'>DEL</button>
<button class='btn btn-orange' data-num='/'>/</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='1'>1</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='2'>2</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='3'>3</button>
<button class='btn btn-orange' data-num='*'>*</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='4'>4</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='5'>5</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='6'>6</button>
<button class='btn btn-orange' data-num='+'>+</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='7'>7</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='8'>8</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='9'>9</button>
<button class='btn btn-orange' data-num='-'>-</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='.'>.</button>
<button class='btn btn-grey' data-num='0'>0</button>
<button class ='span-two equalBtn'>=</button>
</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you but theres still one problem.It works but doesn't appear on the currOp.So it only appears on the console

Comment: Reason of that u need to use innerHTML inspide of value. Because value is for input. But your element is div so u need to say innerHTML. I edited answer.